# Can for loop be used to send bulk mails, Bulk mail Issues, AWS(amazon) SES

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using C# and .net for coding, to send bulk mails around 5000 mails at one shot using AWS(AMazon) SES(Simple Email Service) API, Everything is working fine if the number of mails sending are less than 500-600(approximately), but if it is more like 5000 it will send upto 500-600 and then it will stop sending emails. I have used datatable to store the mails list from database, assigned template body and subject, and then used for loop to send emails one by one. I need to know whether it is coding problem or for loop issue or some other thing ? Any suggestion is also helpful to me?

```
for (i = 0; i < dtable1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        Object a=dtable1.Rows[i]["student_emailid"];
        String TO1=Convert.ToString(a);
        TO1 = TO1.Trim();
        if (TO1.Equals("")) {
            continue;
        }
        const String FROM = "asit@amcsquare.com";   // Replace with your "From" address. This address must be verified.
        String TO = TO1;  // Replace with a "To" address. If your account is still in the
        // sandbox, this address must be verified.

        String SUBJECT = email_subject;
        String BODY = templateBody;


        // Supply your SMTP credentials below. Note that your SMTP credentials are different from your AWS credentials.
        const String SMTP_USERNAME = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";  // Replace with your SMTP username. 
        const String SMTP_PASSWORD = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";  // Replace with your SMTP password.

        // Amazon SES SMTP host name. This example uses the us-west-2 region.
        const String HOST = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";

        // Port we will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint. We are choosing port 587 because we will use
       // STARTTLS to encrypt the connection.
        const int PORT = 587;


        // Create an SMTP client with the specified host name and port.
        using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(HOST, PORT))
        {
            // Create a network credential with your SMTP user name and password.
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

                //Use SSL when accessing Amazon SES. The SMTP session will begin on an unencrypted connection, and then 
               //the client will issue a STARTTLS command to upgrade to an encrypted connection using SSL.
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message1 = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(FROM, TO, SUBJECT, BODY);

            message1.IsBodyHtml = true;
            client.Send(message1);

        }




    }
```

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages?

Comment: Amazon is probably throttling your email. 5000 is a lot, and you would most likely need a dedicated mail server specifically for mass mail

Comment: How about windows service to process batch by batch?

Comment: I have checked now. I am getting an error saying -----  Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException: The server request timed out.

Comment: what is your **Sending Quota** on SES?

Comment: 70 emails/ second and 500000 emails /day

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason why it is working now, but it's working. I changed the logic of the above code, it started working. Instead of fetching the SMTP connection each time, for sending each mail previously, this time I fetched the smtp connection only once and used it to send all the bulk mails at once and it started working.But the problem is the sending time, it is taking too much to send all the mails.Anyways I will find the solution for this also.

```
using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(HOST, PORT))
{
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    for(i=0;i<mail.Count;i++)

            {
                String TO = mail[i];
                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message1 = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(FROM, TO, SUBJECT, BODY);

                message1.IsBodyHtml = true;

                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.Send(message1);

            }

    client.Dispose();

}

Label1.Text = mail.Count.ToString() + " mails sent !!";
```

}